# How to authenticate user with passport-google on react side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I'm having challenges authenticating users using passport-google on the front end.

Currently i have an application which allows you to register and login locally, after that a token is sent, and that token is being passed in react. If a token is set, then the application is authenticated on the front end, if there is no user token the front end(react side) is unauthenticated.

How can i use use this logic with [passport-google](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/google/) ?

At the moment, this logic gives me a cors error. And i have cors enabled and stuff, and my react port server is accepted as the cors origin. Express is running on 3000, and react is on running on 3001.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&scope=profile&client_id=414221829387-squf9po9h437tjkknkc0c4foq6734fo7.apps.googleusercontent.com'
>   (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/users/auth/google') from
>   origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

*Axios has base url set to localhost:3000*

How im calling the passport google on the client side.

```
render(){ 
       const googleLogin = response => {
            let googleData;
            googleData = {
              googleID: response.profileObj.googleId,
              email: response.profileObj.email,
              password: "",
            };

            this.props.googleLogin(googleData);
          };      
        return(
           ........
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                 ....                        
                </form>
                <div>
                  <GoogleLogin
                    clientId={'******'}
                    render={renderProps => (
                      <GoogleLoginButton
                        className="googleBtn"
                        alt="googleLogo"
                        onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                        align={"center"}
                      >     
                      </GoogleLoginButton>
                    )}
                    buttonText="Login with Google"
                    onSuccess={googleLogin}
                    onFailure={googleLogin}
                    className="googleComponentBtn"
                    theme="dark"
                  />             
                </div>           
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Here is my attempt,

**App.js( here were fetching the token)**

```
// JWT TOKEN
if (sessionStorage.jwtToken) {
  // Set auth token header auth
  setAuthToken(sessionStorage.jwtToken);
  // Decode token and get user info and exp
  const decoded = jwt_decode(sessionStorage.jwtToken);
  // Set user and isAuthenticated
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
  // Check for expired token
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    // Logout user
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());
    // Redirect to login
    window.location.href = "/login";
  }
}


class App extends Component {


  render(){
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
         <Navbar/>
      </Provider>
    );

  }

}

export default App;
```

**authActions.js**

```
// how the local login works to get an idea
export const loginUser = userData => dispatch => {
    Axios.post('/users/login', userData)
        .then( res => {
            // retrieve token from the response 
            const token = res.data.token;
            console.log(token);
            // pass the token in session
            sessionStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
            // set the auth token
            setAuthToken(token);
            // decode the auth token
            const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
            // pass the decoded token
            dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded))

        })
        .catch(err => {
            if(err.response.data){
                console.log(err.response)
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_ERRORS,
                    payload: err.response.data
                })
            }

        })
}
// attempt to login with google, and recieve a token from routes. 
export const googleLogin = () => dispatch => {
    Axios
      .get('/users/auth/google', userData)
      .then(res => {
        const { token } = res.data;
        // Set token to ls
        sessionStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
        // Set token to Auth header
        setAuthToken(token);
        // Decode token to get user data
        const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
        // Set current user
        dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

// set logged in user 

export const setCurrentUser = (decoded, dispatch) => {
    return{
        type:SET_CURRENT_USER,
        payload:decoded
    }
}
```

**routes/users** Attempt to pass token to react

```
router.get('/auth/google',  
    passport.authenticate('google', { scope: 'profile'}),  (req, res, next) => {
        console.log(profile);
        jwt.sign(process.env.JWT_SECRET,{expiresIn: 4800}, (err, token) => {
            res.json({
                success:true, 
                token: token
            })
        });
});

router.get('/auth/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
   (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

**passport.js**

```
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
  {
  clientID: process.env.clientID,
  clientSecret: process.env.secret,
  callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback',
  // proxy: true
  }, (token, tokenSecret, profile, done) => {

    // console.log(profile);
    User.forge({ googleId: profile.id}).fetch() 
      .then( (err, user) => {
        if(!user){
          const googleUser = new User({
            googleId: profile.id,
            email:profile.emails[0].value
          });

          googleUser.save().then( user => done(null, user))
        }else{
          done(null, user)
          console.log(user);
        }
      })

   }
))

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
      });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
        User
          .forge({id: user})
          .fetch()
          .then((usr) => {
            done(null, usr);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            done(err);
          });
    });
```

Comment: `passport-google` and `passport-google-oauth` are not maintained and don't work. you should use `passport-google-oauth-2`, also if you are using jwt's with your app, then `passport-session` is not gonna work great with `express-jwt`. the way I did it in our app was with callbacks only instead of built in middleware. unfortunately i can't share any code, but i can tell you how it works in a nutshell.

Comment: ok no wonder why its not working. So i will update to passport-google-oauth-2

Comment: @r3wt  So you have a similar scenario when you authenticated users with passport-google-oauth-2 and was able to authenticate the client-side as well ? would you be able to show similar code then ?

Comment: hopefully this is self explanatory https://jsfiddle.net/nLypbzhw/2/

Comment: ok thanks will check this out. thx.